# Test behavior that depends on Vue event bus

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

In our application, we have a singleton `Confirmation.vue` component which is leveraged by a composable `useConfirmation.ts`. This composable is used both by `Confirmation.vue` (mostly, as a source of state) and by consumer components. It has the `show` method that returns a Promise. In case a user clicks on whether 'accept', 'cancel' or 'other' button, that Promise gets resolved with a corresponding action name the user has chosen. Eventually, consumer components can handle the result.

In order to make this work, I've added an even bus. For example, when user clicks on the 'accept' button, the even `on-accept` gets dispatched via the event bus. Then, I listen for this event in the `useConfirmation` composable and resolve the promise with the corresponding action type. It looks approximately like this (I omitted type declarations for simplicity):

ConfirmationEvenBus.ts:

```
export function emitConfirmationModalAccept() {
  confirmationModalEventBus.$emit(CONFIRMATION_MODAL_ACCEPT);
}

export function onConfirmationModalAccept(cb) {
  confirmationModalEventBus.$on(CONFIRMATION_MODAL_ACCEPT, cb);
}
```

Confirmation.vue:

```
function handleAccept() {
  emitConfirmationModalAccept();
}
```

useConfirmation.ts:

```
const options = ref({ ...defaultOptions });

export function useConfirmation() {
   let resolveFn = null;
  
   ...
   
   function show(modalOptions) {
     setOptions({ ...modalOptions, visible: true });

     return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolveFn = resolve;
     });
   }

  ...

  onMounted(() => {
    onConfirmationModalAccept(() => {
      if (resolveFn) {
        resolveFn(ModalActionTypes.ACCEPT);
      }
    });
  })

  return {
   ...
  }
}
```

The problems started during the testing of the `useConfirmation.ts`. I have no idea how to simulate the behavior of the event bus and test the callback of the `onMounted`. Do you have any idea on how to do this? It would be nice to check, for example, if the `show` method resolves with the correct result or that the event bus has been deactivated after the `onBeforeUnmount` callback had been called.

FYI, we're using Vue 2.7 with the Composition API. The testing framework is Jest (enhanced by the `vue-test-utils`)